# Drupal 6 Get file object from file store

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a file stored in the drupal file table. I need to get a $file object to save as a CCK field. How can I get $file object out of the file table in the DB?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the ID of the file, you could just use a query

```
$results = db_result(db_query("SELECT * FROM {files} WHERE fid = %d", 3));
```

You can of course alter the query to match your known information.

Depending on your result, you may also want to use `db_fetch_array` or `db_fetch_object`.

Then you can use `$file = field_file_save_file($path, $validators, $drupal_destination)` to save if with the help of [CCK FileField](http://drupal.org/project/filefield).

Now you can use $file array to store as CCK Field.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$fileObject = db_fetch_object(db_query("SELECT * FROM {files} WHERE fid = %d", $fid));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best option, but I use [field_file_load()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!filefield!field_file.inc/function/field_file_load/6). You might have to cast returned file to objects:

```
 $file = (object)field_file_load($fid);
```